# Longest Even word

Tags: javascript

I need to find the longest even word from a sentence.

I've tried this code for finding the largest word.

But I need the even word.

Can anyone please help me?

```
function FindlongestWord(input) {
  var arrWords = input.split(' ');
  var wordlength = 0;
  var word = '';
  arrWords.forEach(function(wrd) {
    if (wordlength < wrd.length) {
      wordlength = wrd.length;
      word = wrd;
    }
  });
  return word;
}
```

Comment: What is an *"even"* word?

Comment: what is the expected result if there are no even words in the sentence?

Comment: even word means word with character-length divisible by 2, or word at position 2,4,6,8 and so on..In any case, it is a if check in loop.

Comment: even length word.

Comment: Ok..I got the answer.

function FindlongestWord(input) {
  var arrWords = input.split(' ');
  var wordlength = 0;
  var word = '';
  arrWords.forEach(function(wrd) {
    if (wordlength < wrd.length) {
      wordlength = wrd.length;
      word = wrd;
    }
  });
  return word;
}

Answer (score 2):

Using modulus operator in the if statement

```
arrWords.forEach(function(wrd) {
if (wordlength < wrd.length && wrd.length % 2 == 0) {
  wordlength = wrd.length;
  word = wrd;
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution.

```js
const longestWord = (str) => str.split(' ').filter(v => !(v.length % 2))
                                           .sort((a,b) => b.length - a.length)[0];

console.log(longestWord('hi there hello four longer longestt'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function FindlongestWord(input) {
  var arrWords = input.split(' ');
  var wordlength = 0;
  var word = '';
  arrWords.forEach(function(wrd) {
    if (wordlength < wrd.length && !wrd.length%2) {
      wordlength = wrd.length;
      word = wrd;
    }
  });
  return word;
}
```